# nltk successfully installed, but now I can't import it

Tags: nltk, python-3.4

I just installed nltk and now it's not working, and I need assistance figuring out what's wrong.

I followed the install guide here [https://pythonprogramming.net/tokenizing-words-sentences-nltk-tutorial/][1]

Installed via pip

```
sudo pip install nltk
```

Then I launched python and downloaded all components

```
# python3
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.download()
```

This worked, and it downloaded all the components(I chose all).  After which I figured I was good to go.  However, then I went to write my first script and it errored out on the 1st line which imported nltk.

Now when I open the python interpreter I get

```
# python3
>>> import nltk
"2016-03-02 04:34:03,630","regex.py","ERROR","There is a problem with your SQL query: SELECT regex, regex_id FROM regex WHERE type = 'date'"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nick/booze-dev/regex.py", line 10, in <module>
cursor.execute(SQL) # Execute SQL
NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
from nltk.chunk import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/api.py", line 15, in <module>
from nltk.chunk.util import ChunkScore
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/chunk/util.py", line 13, in <module>
from nltk.tag.mapping import map_tag
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/tag/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
from nltk.tag.sequential    import (SequentialBackoffTagger, ContextTagger,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/tag/sequential.py", line 25, in <module>
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/classify/__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
from nltk.classify.textcat import TextCat
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/nltk/classify/textcat.py", line 47, in <module>
import regex as re
File "/home/nick/booze-dev/regex.py", line 14, in <module>
sys.exit("Aborting script execution")
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```

I didn't get that error the 1st time I ran the import and executed nltk.download(), so I'm not understanding why I'm getting it now.

I've tried executing python as root and my normal user, and get the same error.

If I check my sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/lib/python3.4', '/usr/lib/python3.4/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

I can find nltk under /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages:

```
# ls /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages | grep nltk
nltk
nltk-3.1.egg-info
```

So it should be available.  So why am I getting an error when importing now?

Comment: Try: `pip3 install -U nltk` or install `conda` conda.pydata.org/docs/install/quick.html

Comment: same thing.  It ran successfully and gave me "Running setup.py install for nltk ... done".  I then launched python3 and ran import nltk & nltk.download() again, which downloaded everything again, quit python.  Script still won't run and when I open the interpreter again, it still won't import the module.

Comment: Ok, figured it out, but not quite sure why it's doing this.  I logged in, su'ed to root, ran pip3 install -U nltk.  I was in my home directory when I did this which put the folder nltk_data in /home/me.  If I run the python3 interpreter from /home/me it works just fine.  If I run it from /home/me/mydevfolder it fails.  Shouldn't the pip installer install the nltk_Data folder somewhere else and add it to sys.path in python automatically?

Comment: I think it's how you've setup your python `env`, see http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/. BTW, NLTK v3.2 just rolled out, you should do a `pip install -U nltk` again. There's quite some bits of bugfixes from v3.1 and all the recent complains on 3rd party tools should be resolved in v3.2.

Comment: I don't think that's it.  I reran the command and got this: Requirement already up-to-date: nltk in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages.  I also don't recall ever setting up a virtual env on this box, and I can't list any virtual env's either: # lsvirtualenv
bash: lsvirtualenv: command not found